# How to restrict to web application to specific Browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am using asp.net in backend and Javascript (ExtJs) in frontend. I want my web app to open in some particular browser. **ex: IE11**. I thought to try `noscript tag` But not getting any idea how to get this.

Suppose I am able detect my browser then How I will restrict to IE 11 only. 
Can anybody suggest what I need to do.

Comment: @Kody There is a difference. How to detect and how to restrict. In case I detect my browser then How I can restrict my application only to that perticular browser.

Comment: @shankysingh Short answer - you can't reliably. The user will always be able to spoof his browser to appear like IE11 (if you check server-side), and will be able to trivially defeat client-side checks. However, if you don't need to do it reliably, then once you have detected the browser, you can simply display a message to the user saying "please go away" or similar - we can't tell you what precisely you should do, as that is determined by your customer requirements, and the look-n-feel of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like the following:

```
var userAgent = window.naviagtor.userAgent;
if (userAgent === 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';) {
     //is IE11
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think IE11 still uses ActiveX, you can try to detect if the browser support ActiveX combine with user-agent.But this is not necessarily to say if the browser doesn't support ActiveX is not IE11, like security is on ...